# How to convert IP address (both ipv4 and ipv6) to binary in C++?

Tags: c++, ip

I have a string representing an ip address, it can be both ipv4 and ipv6.

What I want is to convert it to a decimal form from which I can then get individual bits.

For example, for address represented by string "192.168.0.1" I would like to get a decimal 3232235521.

The best would be to use some standard library, for example the function [inet_pton](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html) would do great. But I can't get how to use it.

I wrote the following code based on information about sockaddr_in [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip):

```
   struct sockaddr_in sa;
   char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
   // store this IP address in sa:
   inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.1", &(sa.sin_addr));
   cout<<"bin by inet_pton"<<sa.sin_addr.s_addr<<endl;
```

Which gives me 553779392. This number corresponds to 1.0.168.192. Of course, I could write some function for reversing this number somehow, but I am looking for some standard and effective way of converting the ip address to binary.

Comment: The issue in your example is with byte-order. Your host machine is storing the ip-address as little-endian. If you wanted to get your code to work the way you have written it, use htonl(sa.sin_addr.s_addr) to express it as big-endian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I yanked this code from Beej's Guide to Network Programming:

```
struct sockaddr_in antelope;
char *some_addr;

inet_aton("10.0.0.1", &antelope.sin_addr); // store IP in antelope

some_addr = inet_ntoa(antelope.sin_addr); // return the IP
printf("%s\n", some_addr); // prints "10.0.0.1"

// and this call is the same as the inet_aton() call, above:
antelope.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1");
```

What we have here is an example of moving an ip address back and forth between the type of struct which is generally used for storing address info and a string. The last line of this code is basically what you need. The integer representation of the ip address is being stored in antelope.sin_addr.s_addr. s_addr is just an unsigned long, so it should be exactly what you need. If you were to do this:

```
cout << antelope.sin_addr.s_addr << endl;
```

you would get the decimal representation of 10.0.0.1

EDIT: I added a comment under your original code to express the issue with the code that you already had, which is basically just an issue with endianness. The code I gave you in this answer might give you the same problem. You need to use htonl() to reverse the byte order.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code does the same as the code I posted above - for 10.0.0.1 it gives me 16777226, which corresponds to 1.0.0.10. Also, inet_addr doesn't support ipv6 (inet_pton does).

Comment: I have just noticed your comment, yes htonl() works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @2to1mux - I bolded the text that saved my behind.  At first, second, and third glance your string to struct and struct to string was NOT helping me.  FINALLY!!!  I read deeper and discovered the answer to getting the IP Address from a string to a integer hidden (to me) in the text.  This is a GREAT answer.  Upvoted it for you, buddy.  Thanks A-LOT.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**For retrieving the *INTEGER* representation of the ip address:**

We need to pay close attention to the following information in @2to1mux's post.

**The integer representation of the ip address is being stored in antelope.sin_addr.s_addr.**

**s_addr is just an unsigned long**

Example:

```
struct sockaddr_in antelope;

// Here I had to convert from NSString to c string
inet_pton(AF_INET, [ipAddress UTF8String], &(antelope.sin_addr));

// This line gets the integer value
UInt32 address = antelope.sin_addr.s_addr;
```

I hope this additional post makes it crystal clear to the confused, like me.

Answer (score 0):

Landed here, searching for an elegant solution to test if an IP address was between a given pair of IP addresses.
Here's my 2 cents building on the solution by @2to1mux. Just putting it all together in case someone needs a fully working example.  Can this be modified to handle IPV6?

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
           
    size_t ip_to_num(int family, char *IP)
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in antelope;
        inet_pton(family, IP, &(antelope.sin_addr));
        i = ntohl(antelope.sin_addr.s_addr);
        
        return i;
    }
    
   
    void print_num_to_ip(int family, size_t i)
    {
        /* This structure is actually not required here.
            Added just to show how numbers can be transformed into valid socket structures.
        */        
        struct sockaddr_in antelope; 
    
        memset(&antelope, 0, sizeof(antelope));
        antelope.sin_family = family;
        antelope.sin_port = htons(0);
    
        antelope.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(i);
        printf("IP: %zu [%s] \n", i, inet_ntoa(antelope.sin_addr));    
    }
    
    int main ()
    {
        char IP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]="192.168.0.2";
        size_t x = 0;
        
        x = ip_to_num(AF_INET, IP);
        
        printf("IP: %zu [%s] \n", x, IP);
        
        print_num_to_ip(AF_INET, x);
        
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```